# Create random rss feed from 8 html static pages

Tags: html, php, rss

I need to create an rss feed that update about 3/4 times in a day with random post taken from 8 html static pages. There's a software or php script to make that or something else?

Comment: Do you mean these 8 pages will keep coming again and again?

Comment: I've a standard block for photogallery. I'd like to random take those photos and mix them in a rss feed, updating it about 3 times in a day.

Comment: Are the images stored in a folder on your PHP server, and accessible from the Internet already?

Comment: Yes They are, but I need also to import title and description from the html file. Is a static site not php